# MySQL row to columns

Tags: mysql, row

I have searched all over the internet and I have had no luck in finding the answer to my question. I hope this has not specifically been posted yet.

I am trying to change the data from row to columns.

Here is my current query:

`SELECT * FROM wp_rg_lead_detail ORDER BY id`

Gives me the result below:

`id   lead_id form_id field_number   value
1       1      1        1           A
2       1      1        2           B
3       1      1        3           C
4       2      1        1           A
5       2      1        2           B
6       2      1        3           C`

The lead_id is the spesific entry and the field number is the order of the value.

The result I am looking for is:

`|Column 1|Column 2|Column 3|
----------------------
| 1 |   2 |     3 |
| A |   B |     C |`

If my tables is confusing, please see attached images here:

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru6od.png)

[Wished result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BX1f.png)

Any help or pointers would be highly appricated.

Comment: Your results don't make sense.  Where do the "1", "2", and "3" come from in the first row of the desired result?

Comment: Ahhh,,, the un-abandoned joy of trying to write SQL against an implementation of an EAV model, I suggest OP do a google search "**sql for eav**".   @GordonLinoff: the "1", "2" and "3" are the attribute identifiers, stored in "field_number".

Comment: Thank you for notifying that @spencer7593

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . Those make sense as column aliases, not as values in the column.

Answer (score 0):

u can choose what u want to show in sql command.

```
SELECT `value`,`field_number` FROM wp_rg_lead_detail ORDER BY id
```

but if u want to change schema of table it's not work.
u can retrieve data with select query thene insert what u want in new table.